# How to return date with space separator instead of T character in MVC4 or in Json.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, javascriptserializer

How to return dates in json in ISO format but separated with space instead of T in ASP.NET MVC4 application controller

ASP.NET standard Json() method returns dates in Microsoft format and it looks like this cannot customized.

I tried Newtonsoft Json.NET.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data)
```

returns date in proper ISO format but with T character:

```
2013-11-17T18:14:32
```

How to return dates so that space is used instead of T like

```
2013-11-17 18:14:32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by creating a new `IsoDateTimeConverter` instance, specifying the `DateTimeFormat` you want, and then passing that converter to `SerializeObject()`.

Demo:

```
var data = new { MyDate = new DateTime(2013, 11, 17, 18, 41, 26, 835) };

IsoDateTimeConverter dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK"
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, dateConverter);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{"MyDate":"2013-11-17 18:41:26.835"}
```